# how to escape brackets in regex replace in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is not working as expected :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('This is testing data SIL(TM)T for once ', 
'SIL(TM)T', 'SIL<REFERENCE ID="8208" TYPE="trademark"/>T')as 
Newdescriptiontext from dual
```

output should be:

`This is testing data SIL<REFERENCE ID="8208" TYPE="trademark"/>T for once`

which is not the case .Need guidance .

Answer (score 1):

try replace instead of regexp_replace

```
SELECT REPLACE('This is testing data SIL(TM)T for once ', 
'SIL(TM)T', 'SIL<REFERENCE ID="8208" TYPE="trademark"/>T')as 
Newdescriptiontext from dual;
```

Comment: Hi @schurik it is working but can you tell why it was not in regexp_replace.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to escape the parentheses:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('This is testing data SIL(TM)T for once ', 
                       'SIL\(TM\)T', 'SIL<REFERENCE ID="8208" TYPE="trademark"/>T')as Newdescriptiontext
from dual
```

In a regexp, they are used to delimit a "subexpression", so `'(TM)'` matches `'TM'`; if you escape them, they'll be interpreted as plain characters, thus having `'\(TM\)'` matching `'(TM)'`